# FortiClient VPN on Linux Client VirtualBox breaks the Network Connectivity

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vpn, fortigate, forticlient

I have a Windows 10 host running an Ubuntu VirtualBox client VM. I want to set up Forticlient SSL-VPN on the Ubuntu Client and am able to successfully do so, even restarting the VM is fine.

But as soon as I restart the Windows 10 host and attempt to reconnect to the VM, the internet connectivity is broken.

I have tried switching the network adapter between NAT & Bridged with no success, and from reading online there are only guides on fixing issues when the host is the one with the VPN connection.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found to work was to add another network adapter to the VirtualBox machine.

I had the first as NAT > Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop, and then when I added adapter 2, Bridged > Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201, the internet seems to work.

My guess is Forticlient messes with the adapter inside the VM, and adding another allows it to bypass it.